# Null form JSON file when using dataWithContentsOfURL

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json

I'm trying to connect to a JSON file on my server (witch is a valid JSON file), but it returns NULL(jsonData is NULL not the json). The code works whit other url's but not with mine, and when loaded in a web browser every thing is fine.

Here is the code i'm using.

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error = nil;
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: Is jsonData nil or json? If json is nil, what is the error?

Comment: Without more information, this is impossible to answer. What's the URL you're hitting, what does the response look like? Does error have anything in it after the `JSONObjectWithData:` method returns?

Comment: The jsonData is NULL and the app crashes when i try to log json

Answer (score 2):

Use the following method to get the possible error in loading the data with your url:

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                                         options:NSDataReadingUncached
                                           error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
} else {
    // ... do stuff
}
```

A common error to occur in a development environment is when the server you are calling is on a local network and you are trying to access from a device on an external network. Make sure this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are passing url as string. Passed it as a url. Use this for converting into data:-

```
 NSData *jsonData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yoururlString]];
```

Comment: That method does not exist on `NSData`. You probably meant `NSJSONSerialization`, but *that* method does not accept a URL as an argument.